# ASP.NET Webservice- SessionState not timingout

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a web application that utilizes JQuery as my front end code and ASP.NET as my backend web service.

I set the web.config setting  `<sessionState timeout="1">`. When the user logs in, the web service creates a session variable with the user name.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = user_id;
```

In my web service, I have a function that checks if the variable still exists.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string GetSessionUserID()
{
    string user_id = "";
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] != null)
    {
        user_id = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();
    }
    return user_id;
}
```

I have a JS function that calls the web service that calls `GetSessionUserID()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            getSessionID();
            setInterval(getSessionID, 3000);
        function getSessionID() {
            console.log("getSessionID");
            $.ajax({
                url: "photoapp.asmx/GetSessionUserID",
                //data: ,
                success: OnGetSessionIDSuccess,
                error: OnGetSessionIDError
            });
        }
        function OnGetSessionIDSuccess(data, status) {
            console.log("Success OnGetSessionIDSuccess");
            console.log(data);
            var strUser = $(data).find("string").text();
            console.log(strUser);
            if (strUser == "") {
                window.location = "login.html";
            }
        }
}
```

In the document ready function, I also call `setInterval()` which will check the session every 3 seconds.

When testing, `getSessionID` gets called every 3 seconds, but after a minute, the getSessionID user variable can be found. I want the redirect the user back to login.html after the minute is done. Why is the session variable still alive after a minute? What am I not understanding about ASP.Net session state? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if you adopt SQL server to save the session state, then the session timeout events never get called, and you thus can't know or tell if the user actually has logged out.

The only possible solution then is to ensure that all web pages have some kind of heartbeat or routine that calls the server every minute or so, and when that stops, then you know the user is gone or closed the web page.

In your case? If you touch the server every 3 seconds, then the session timeout will be re-set and start over with 1 minute. You also don't mention if you using in-memory, or using sql server for session state.

If you want to jump back to the logon page? Then your 3 second js code has to get/grab the time of the last heartbeat you call every 3 seconds. So, that routine has to set a start time, and then every 3 seconds check the elapsed time. Keep in mind that if  you use sql sessions, then not even the logon event will fire, nor will even the authenticated user event fire.
So, the first time you start running that routine, you need to set a session value with the start time.

However, to my knowledge, every web service call will re-set the session time out to start over to 0. session timeout gets re-set when no activity occurs. So, if the user is doing something (or your ajax calls are), then session timeout will never occur.

You have to set a start time. And then get the elapsed time from that. You session will never timeout as long as you have the web page hitting and talking to the server.